# Java String to Int doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a simple calculator that is automatic - no more equal sign. 
Here's how it should go:
1. User inputs the first number.
2. User chooses an operation "add", "subtract" etc. 
3. User inputs the second number. In this stage, the program should now automatically compute the answer. For example:
user inputs "2" as the first number;
user chooses  "add";
user inputs  "3" (second number this time)
it should then display "5" in the result box. 
if the user continues to input "2", this means the second number is now "32" instead of "3", and the result will be "34"
Here's my code:

```
public String int_firstnumber   = "";
public String int_secondnumber  = "";
public int int_result           = 0;
public int int_numberone        = 0;
public int int_numbertwo        = 0;

public String str_operation     = "";
public String str_inputdisplay  = "";

public String str_indicator     = "none";
public String str_focus         = "first";

// BUTTON 1
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


           //checks the indicator
            if(str_focus=="first") {
                int_firstnumber = int_firstnumber +"1";
                lblinput.setText(int_firstnumber + str_operation + int_secondnumber);
            } else {
                if(str_indicator=="add"){
                    int_secondnumber = int_secondnumber + "1";
                    lblinput.setText(int_firstnumber + str_operation + int_secondnumber);
                    int_numberone = Integer.parseInt(int_firstnumber);
                    int_numbertwo = Integer.parseInt(int_secondnumber);
                    int_result = int_numberone + int_numbertwo;


                    lblresult.setText(int_result);
                }

            }


        }
    });
    //END OF BUTTON 1


//BUTTON ADD
    btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            str_indicator = "add";
            str_operation = " + ";
            str_focus = "second";
            lblinput.setText(int_firstnumber + str_operation + int_secondnumber);
        }
    });
```

This somewhat works but not completely. If I Input "1", it'll display `1` on the `str_inputdisplay`, I then click the `+` symbol or the `btnadd`, it then displays `1+` in the `str_inputdisplay`. This means that we are on the second number right? However when I input `1` again, the app just force closes. 

Any ideas why this is happening? Forgive my ways of code, I just started learning Java btw. Thanks!

Comment: For starter, for string comparison you can't use `==` - You have to compare two strings like this `str_indicator.equals("add")`

Comment: If you just started i suggest you to follow some tutorials first and debug the code to know exactly what going on .

Comment: @Sharj It says "method call expected"

Comment: Can you post your exception from Logcat which results in app crash on second button click? And I am not able to see the code for str_focus=="second" condition code if you forget to add here then add to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you naming your variable 'int_firstnumber' when it's a string `public String int_firstnumber` when all your other variables are named according to the variable type like `int int_result` and `str_operation`

your code looks a bit more complicated then it needs to be. as someone mentioned you can't add two numbers when your operator is a string i.e. `string operator = "+";` it won't get treated like an operand, it will get treated for the type it is which is a string.

why not if they select "first" call a method *setFirstNumber* that way you can validate input and set the first number.. something like this:

```
public void setFirstNumber(int firstNumber){
    int_numberone = firstNumber;
}
```

and then when "add" gets selected call a second method *setSecondNumber* along with an addition method

```
public void setSecondNumber(int secondNumber){
    int_numbertwo = secondNumber;'
}
```

and

```
public int addNumbers(int firstNumber, int secondNumber){
    return firstNumber + secondNumber;
}
```

your result will be `int_result = addNumbers(int_numberOne, int_numberTwo)`

this way your code is much cleaner, each function is executing one task, and if you want to add additional operations later it's easy to add a function subtract, multiply, etc

```
public int subtractNumbers(int firstNumber, int secondNumber){
    return firstNumber - secondNumber;
}

public int multiplyNumbers(int firstNumber, int secondNumber){
    return firstNumber * secondNumber;
}
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. When adding two strings, addition will not happen. Change it to int, long etc when you want to do operation like:

   ```
       int_firstnumber = int_firstnumber +"1";
   ```
2. Hopefully you are properly setting the variables str_focus and str_indicator because that is not available in the code snippet you have given.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if("first".equals(str_focus)) {
                     ......
                   int_firstnumber = int_firstnumber +1;
            } else {
                if("add".equals(str_indicator)){
                  ......
                  int_secondnumber = int_secondnumber + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add TextWatcher to the input fields. You will get the values in callbaks there which you can use to update the view showing answer.